# Limit Results when posting in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am pretty new to wordpress so please forgive me if this has been answered previously as I was unable to find it when I searched..

I want to call up the categories an advert is listed in but limit the results to just '3'.

This is what I have so far:

```
<?php if ( $post->post_type == 'post' ) the_category(', '); else echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, APP_TAX_CAT, '', ', ', ''); ?>
```

So how can I edit this to limit the results to just 3 categories please.

Answer (score 0):

[get_the_term_list](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list) is simply a helper function that assumes you want to output all terms associated with a post as markup. If you want to control the terms that are returned beforehand, use [get_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) instead.

Also, don't write all of your PHP on one line. That's terrible practice, and makes whoever has to inherit your code want to kick puppies.

```
<?php
if ( $post->post_type == 'post' ){
    the_category(', ');
}
else{
    $terms = get_terms(APP_TAX_CAT, array('number'=>3, 'fields'=>'names'));
    echo implode(', ', $terms);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly.  I did not write the PHP, it was a theme I purchased and I am having to make a whole load of changes to make it work the way I want.. I thought it would be easier than starting from scratch, however this has turned out not to be the case, so thanks for the assist, much appreciated.

Comment: @DemonLee Glad it worked out for you. When you have a moment, please mark this as accepted so that others with similar problems can use this information.

Comment: Sorry, how do I mark this as 'accepted, I can see no button or link to do that or is this post acceptable?

Comment: White checkmark below the score next to the answer.